# Block Permission for user

Tags: users

I have faced a new problem, here I have poll block which is already displayed for administrator or user who has the permission of "view published content". When I made another user and give the complete permission for the poll but does not giver the permission of "view published content", it is not displayed for the user. Can any one help me to show that in the block for user except administer or user who has the permission of "view published content".

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You want to be looking at the permission "vote on polls" that is the one you want to enable for that user.

Comment: yes, I want to enable the poll block for another users without having the permission of "view published content". Could you help me

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Comment: yes, I rad your answer but it did not make any sense for me. My question is this that I want to display the block for some users and there is no difference weather it is poll block or any other block